# reveal.js build PDF's dynamically with grunt-lib-phantomjs

Tags: pdf, gruntjs, reveal.js

I am looking for a solution to build PDFs dynamically for several presentations in a grunt.js task. My idea was to use `grunt-lib-phantomjs` with the plugin script `print-pdf.js` from reveal.js. But I don't understand how to configure the `grunt-lib-phantomjs` to work with the plugin script.

Can some one explain me how the grunt task must look like? Or is there a better solution as `grunt-lib-phantomjs`?

Answer (score 1):

After some tests and searching I think `grunt-lib-phantomjs` is the wrong way. I use now  native phantomjs and require it in my grunt task.

Install phantomjs:

```
npm install phantomjs
```

My Grunt task:

```js
grunt.registerTask('build_pdf', function () {

 var
   childProcess  = require('child_process'),
   phantomjs     = require('phantomjs'),
   binPath       = phantomjs.path,
   done          = grunt.task.current.async()
 ;

 var childArgs = [
   'print-pdf.js',
   'http://localhost:9000/index.html?print-pdf',
   'slide.pdf'
 ];

 childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function (error, stdout, stderr)
 {
   grunt.log.writeln(stdout);
   done(error);
 })
});
```

print-pdf.js:

```js
/**
 * phantomjs script for printing presentations to PDF.
 *
 * Example:
 * phantomjs print-pdf.js "http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js?print-pdf" reveal-demo.pdf
 *
 * By Manuel Bieh (https://github.com/manuelbieh)
 */

'use strict';

var
  page        = new WebPage(),
  system      = require('system'),
  revealFile  = system.args[1] || 'index.html?print-pdf',
  slidePath   = system.args[2] || ''
;

page.viewportSize = {
    width:  1024,
    height: 768
};

page.paperSize = {
    format:       'letter',
    orientation:  'landscape',
    border:       '0px',
    margin:       '0px'
};

//console.log('Printing PDF for "' + revealFile + '" ...');

page.open(revealFile, function (/*status*/)
{
  var slideFile = slidePath + page.title.replace(' :: ', '__') + '.pdf';

  console.log('Printed succesfully');
    page.render(slideFile, {format: 'pdf', quality: '100'});
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: interesting, can you please show the print-pdf.js file?